# Lenovo g580 Overheating with Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, cpu, fan

I just installed Fedora 25 and everything is working great , except for the CPU Fans. They are rotating at a pretty slow speed and that is causing my laptop to overheat.

I have installed TLP and still it is overheating. How do I solve this.

P.S : Please say what necessary system details that I need to post.